# Conga template with apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, conga

Hi I am new to apex code and I need to create a trigger that fires off a call to appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PM.aspx when I tick a check box on a custom object. I am looking to update the checkbox via data loader and pass conga loader values from a report. At the moment I have this working from a custom button that conga has assisted in configuring, so I have an idea of what needs to happen.

Thanks in advance
David

My custom object is called Sabre_Hotels and the item is First_Email_Sent__c

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have read the documentation from conga listed below

http://www.congasphere.com/search-results.html?fuzeurl=http%3A//knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/ext/kbdetail.aspx%3Fkbid%3D69

http://www.congasphere.com/search-results.html?fuzeurl=http%3A//knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/ext/kbdetail.aspx%3Fkbid%3D73

Answer (score 1):

I'm the Senior Product Specialist at Conga. Thanks for posting the question.

This sounds like a perfect use case for Conga Workflow. Conga Workflow allows you to use a standard SFDC Workflow rule, wrapping a Composer process into that rule.

It's a simple and quick process to turn a working Composer solution into a Conga Workflow solution. Check out the documentation [here](http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/wf/uploadfiles/files/Conga%20Workflow%20%28Release%208%29.pdf) and an overview of Conga Workflow is available [here](http://www.congamerge.com/products/composer/add-ons#workflow).

Feel free to reach out to me directly via this thread if I can be of assistance. 
~J